# Citrus plants that grow best in Northern California, and tolerate our zone 9 winters

Tags: containers, citrus

I think I am having some beginner's luck with growing my Bearss Lime tree in a pot. I'd like to grow more of the citrus plants (preferably oranges/mandarins). Any recommendations for a newbie like me? I'd have to grow them in pots, and am looking for a variety that is cold tolerant to our zone 9 winters, which also puts out a good yield. The gardener at my local nursery seems to suggest that orange trees don't particularly give good produce in Northern California climates?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how far north you are, but oranges and lemons do amazingly well in San Jose where my son lives.